# App crashing because "It appears that 'PubNub' is not a valid Fabric Kit"

Tags: ios, swift, pubnub, twitter-fabric, google-fabric

Let me preface by saying that I'm using `CocoaPods` to manage my frameworks. I'm not sure if this really matters, but I thought you might as well know just in case. I'm also running on iOS 10.x with the latest version of Xcode (not beta).

---

My app is crashing on `Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self, PubNub.self])` with the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FABException', reason: '[Fabric] It appears that "PubNub" is not a valid Fabric Kit. Please make sure you only pass Fabric Kits to [Fabric with:].'

I have updated my `PodFile`, cleaned my project, ran on a fresh install, ran on a physical and virtual device, and I've even uninstalled `pod 'PubNub'` and reinstalled it. Nothing seems to be working so far, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**My `AppDelegate` looks like this:**

```
import Fabric
import Crashlytics
import PubNub

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    /* Fabric (Answers) Debug */
    Fabric.sharedSDK().debug = true
    /* Fabric Setup */
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self, PubNub.self])
    return true
}
```

**My `PodFile` looks like this:**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.1'

target 'AppName' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

    # Fabric #
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics', '~>  3.8'
    # PubNub #
    pod 'PubNub/Fabric'

    target 'AppNameTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        # Pods for testing
    end

    target 'AppNameUITests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        # Pods for testing
    end
end
```

**My `Info.plist` code:**

```
<key>Fabric</key>
<dict>
    <key>APIKey</key>
    <string>##############################</string>
    <key>Kits</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>KitInfo</key>
            <dict/>
            <key>KitName</key>
            <string>Crashlytics</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>KitInfo</key>
            <dict>
                <key>publish-key</key>
                <string>##############################</string>
                <key>secret-key</key>
                <string>##############################</string>
                <key>subscribe-key</key>
                <string>##############################</string>
            </dict>
            <key>KitName</key>
            <string>PubNub</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Comment: Did you add pubnub to your Fabric dictionary in your `Info.plist` ?

Comment: Why is your PubNub pod written `pod 'PubNub/Fabric'`? I looked through the Fabric docs and could not find any mention of them requiring you to append "/Fabric" to the end of third party Kits. Have you tried just using `pod 'PubNub'`?

Comment: Also, don't forget to add your Fabric info to the `Info.plist` like @u.gen mentions above. Here's an [example article](http://www.mokacoding.com/blog/how-to-fix-fabric-startup-crash/)

Comment: @gurooj It's set to `pod 'PubNub/Fabric'` because I want to receive PubNub events in Fabric more easily. The installation instructions that reference this pod installation procedure can be found [here](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/pubnub/install).

Comment: @u.gen Yes, I've added PubNub to my Fabric dictionary array in the `Info.plist`.  I've edited my question to show this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm an engineer on Fabric. I tried reproducing the issue you described above, but have not been able to do so. Things seem to work ok with a fresh Swift project and the PubNub/Fabric Cocoapod. My only suspicion is that you somehow ended up with the non-Fabric build of PubNub in your project. If there is anything else I can do to help, feel free to reach out!

Comment: Thanks for helping! If this is the case, how would I go about erasing the old PubNub build and installing the  new Fabric-build?

Comment: A couple things to try: Delete the Pods folder in your workspace and re-run 'pod install'. If you're still having trouble, try getting it running in a fresh Xcode project to see if that is working for you.